# being hacked by neigbor dual sim cloned device and blietooth

Tags: sharing

I work in technology. This has been going on for over a year and a half to two years.  I am being recorded, I have had well over $10,000 stolen, nine cell phones with nine different telephone numbers all hacked and cloned the same day. Analytic states that the hacker is a vendor using dual Sim and a clone device. It took me 20 months to get any law enforcement and involved, and still going on. Any recommendations on how I could stop being recorded